# I have to make a function which takes an array of strings and returns an array with only strings that doesn't start with a vowel

Tags: javascript

Write a function removeVowelKeys, that takes an array of strings keys and returns an array of keys that does not start with a vowel (aeiouy). The letter case does not matter.

**Example :**

```
removeVowelKeys(['alarm', 'chip', 'isValid', 'Advice', 'onClick']); // ['chip']
```

**Here is my attmpt this is the max i could get out of it :**

```
    function removeVowelKeys(keys) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i=0;i<=keys.length;i++){
    if (keys[i][0]!= 'a'||keys[i][0]!= 'e'||keys[i][0]!= 'i'||keys[i][0]!= 'o'||keys[i][0]!= 'u'||keys[i][0]!= 'y'){
      result.push(keys[i])
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: two issues ... 1.  it's `i<keys.length` because array indexes go from 0 ... `length-1` - 2. think of the logic in your if statement ... if the first letter is not a, or it's not e, or it's not i ... etc ... the first letter can only be one thing ... so, at least one of those `!=` comparisons will be true ... you might want AND instead of OR

Comment: You might consider using a regex `match()` function within a `filter()`, but iterating in a `for` loop is fine too.  Also, consider that your solution doesn't account for uppercase entries (e.g., "Advice").

Comment: There will be many solutions for this, I'm guessing its for a class assignment? If so, some of the answers might not have been covered in your class so they might not work for you

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution just incase anyone wants to use regex. It still loops through the keys and grabs the first character of each passed argument, but it checks it against the vowels.

```js
function removeVowelKeys(keys) {
  let result = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i <= keys.length-1; i++) {
     if(!keys[i][0].match(/[aeiuoy]/i)){
       result.push(keys[i])
     }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(removeVowelKeys(['alarm', 'chip', 'isValid', 'Advice', 'onClick']));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this condition is :

```
if (keys[i][0]!= 'a'||keys[i][0]!= 'e'||keys[i][0]!= 'i'||keys[i][0]!= 'o'||keys[i][0]!= 'u'||keys[i][0]!= 'y')
```

that it will match for any alphabet. You are doing an `OR` check.
Take for example `e` and do a dry run. It will psas the first condition.
`a` will pass the second condition.
And if any one of the expression is true, the whole expression returns true.

```js
function removeVowelKeys(keys) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
    if (keys[i][0].toLowerCase()!= 'a'&&keys[i][0].toLowerCase()!= 'e'&&keys[i][0].toLowerCase()!= 'i'&&keys[i][0].toLowerCase()!= 'o'&&keys[i][0].toLowerCase()!= 'u'&&keys[i][0].toLowerCase()!= 'y'){
      result.push(keys[i])
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(removeVowelKeys(['alarm', 'chip', 'isValid', 'Advice', 'onClick']));
```

Besides that, you want your code to run till `i<keys.length`. Arrays are 0 based right.
And to handle case, you would need to lower case as done above.

Comment: and remember kids, keep your code DRY

Comment: true, a `find()` method might be better than multiple `==` checks, but I wanted to be as close to OP's original solution as possible

Comment: I know - wasn't directed at you, and `find` is not the right solution, a `.includes`/`.indexOf` or even a regex match :p

Comment: `find()`/`some()` with a callback will work right? Need to lowercase, so using this. Ofcourse the lower case values can be added in the array like `[a,A,e,E...]`, so includes will work directly too.

Comment: no, don't over complicate it!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can `filter` the array, and on each item check if the item `startsWith` a vowel character from the array with `some` method.

```js
const vowelChar = ['a', 'o', 'e', 'i', 'y', 'u']
console.log(removeVowelKeys(['alarm', 'chip', 'isValid', 'Advice', 'onClick']));
// ['chip']
function removeVowelKeys(keys) {
  return keys.filter(item => !vowelChar.some(c => item.toLowerCase().startsWith(c)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the words which are starts with vowels. Simply use the `Array.prototype.filter` method.

```js
const removeVowelKeys = (arr) => {
  const vowels = 'aeiou';
  // Now filter out the word whose first character is not in the vowels array.
  // Convert the first character to lower case for skipping the case sensitivity.
  return arr.filter(word => !vowels.includes(word.charAt(0).toLowerCase()));
}

const res = removeVowelKeys(['alarm', 'chip', 'isValid', 'Advice', 'onClick']);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Did you know that `String` has an `includes` that works *just like* Array's `include` ... hands up if you learned something (Y did you omit Y?)

Comment: I know that, but when I wrote the solution that didn't come to my head. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it.

```
converter(['alarm', 'chip', 'isValid', 'advice', 'onClick'])

 const converter = (string) => {
    let vowels = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y']
    let newString = string.filter(x => !vowels.includes(x[0].toUpperCase()))
    return newString
}
```

so, first we pass the params array of strings to function, then we create array of vowels to compare if in every first element of the array, we check if is vowel or not.

array.filter() will create new array base on your condition, so this will only return element whose first letter is not vowel.

Answer (score 0):

Array has a `.filter` function that could be a best friend at this problem.

```js
//Arrow function that checks whether string starts with vowel letter
const startsWithVowel = str => /^[aeiouy]/i.test(str);

//Main function that will filter incoming array of strings
const removeVowelKeys = arr => arr.filter(str => !startsWithVowel(str));

//calling our function to filter the array.
let filteredList = removeVowelKeys(['alarm', 'chip', 'isValid', 'Advice', 'onClick']);

//printing the result to console
console.log(filteredList)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const removeVowelKeys = (arr) => {
  let count = 0
  const strConstant = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
  for(let i=0;i< arr.length;i++) {
    if(!strConstant.includes((arr[i][0]).toLowerCase())) {
      arr[count] = arr[i]
      count++
    }
  }
  arr.length = count
  return arr
}
console.log(removeVowelKeys(['alarm', 'chip', 'isValid', 'Advice', 'onClick']))
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76097246/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).